# Adding events to form elements

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, web

Is it a good idea to add individual blur events to every form element on the form. OR is it better to add a Blur event on the Form tag i.e  element istead.(I.e is the parent element too all the form elements)

Comment: This depends upon what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I can't honestly think of a reason to test for blurring on the form...  I would think that in almost all cases, you would use a blur event on each element of the form.   So every time the user left an input field (for example), you could run whatever script / validations you planned on running.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve,

for instance if blurring of each and every form element is going to cause a seperate change (like checking validity or some really awesome option like displaying content related to that)

Go with individual listeners.

But if your case is something where you can re-use the same functionality of code then you should use a single one on the form tag itself.

You can also go for a hybrid option and handle them on both differently.

It depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: dear random downvoter ... reason please ?

Answer (score -1):

Well! it actually depends upon your requirment. Well I personally suggest that if there are not such necessities to put seperate blur event on each element then put it on Form element only because

it will surely annoy your client if he keeps getting blur events and causing destraction for client in case of wrong entry

Again that depends upon necessity of what we intend

Comment: dear random downvoter ... reason please ?